# Why does there seem to be a drift in the Arima simulation of a time series with seasonality?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality

I'm trying to make sense of the basics of time series, and I ran into a [block of code](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/simulating-from-a-specified-seasonal-arima-model/index.html) by Rob Hyndman.

```
library(ggplot2)   
library(forecast)
set.seed(0)
model <- Arima(ts(rnorm(100),freq=4), order=c(1,1,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1),
             fixed=c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))
foo <- simulate(model, nsim=1000)
autoplot(forecast(foo, h=20))
fit <- Arima(foo, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1))
```

I was surprised that, upon plotting the output, it doesn't seem to be stationary discounting the waves of seasonality expected.

[image]

There is probably a very simple explanation that I am overlooking, but I'd like to get some help getting unstuck.

It may be that it's not a good model to begin with, or that the number of samples is not long enough. Perhaps I don't understand the frequency in seasonality. Or simply a misunderstood coding concept with the triple values in the `Arima()`, like `order = c(1,1,1)`.

Comment: The middle $1$ in the triplet $c(1,1,1)$ refers to the amount of *differencing* of the series; in this case, the series $x_t$ is not stationary, but a single difference of $x$, i.e., $x_t - x_{t-1}$, is.  If you change the `order = c(1,1,1)` to `order = c(1,0,1)` for both the nonseasonal and seasonal terms you should get the results you expected.

Comment: @jbowman Doesn't a zero in the middle position (1,0,1) means less differencing, and therefore, less likely that it is stationary? Also, when I try doing so I get this error: `Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : wrong length for 'fixed'`. That is changing to: ` order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1)`. Did it work for you?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding stationarity. A *series* can be stationary or non-stationary. And differencing is one (!) possible way of addressing it, by turning a non-stationary series into a stationary one. You simulated IID data, which is completely stationary, so the "correct" model should not use differencing. The data generating process is ARIMA(0,0,0). Your question is about the behavior of a misspecified model, where the differencing and summing for forecasting gives you a non-stationary *forecasted* series.

Comment: @StephanKolassa In your comment, "Your simulated IID data" = `ts(rnorm(100),freq=4)`, right? This is the ARIMA(0,0,0) of your comment... Why does `Arima(ts(rnorm(100),freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1), fixed=c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))` gives an error?

Comment: Good question, that one is rather cryptic. `?Arima` tells us that `fixed` is not one of its parameters, and that all "other" parameters get passed to `arima()`, which is a different command. `?arima` tells us that `fixed` should be of the same length as the number of parameters... which seems to be the case, right? So try the `Arima` command *without* the `fixed` parameter, and you see that the model has *five* parameters, not four, because `include.mean` is by default `TRUE`. So just add a fifth entry to your `fixed` parameter, and it works.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Why does the need to specify a mean depends on differencing or not the seasonal component? Compare `Arima(ts(rnorm(100), freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1), fixed = c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))` to `Arima(ts(rnorm(100), freq=4), order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1), fixed = c(phi=0.5, theta=-0.4, Phi=0.3, Theta=-0.2))`.

Comment: Per `?arima`, the `include.mean` parameter is by default `TRUE` for models without differencing, and is ignored for models with differencing.